# Is it ok to use the adjective "known" in this context?

Tags: adjectives

Is it ok to use the adjective "known" in the following context?

> "The first **known** anatomist was Herophilos"

I mean to say that he is the first anatomist that we know for a moment, but it could be that some day we will discover someone earlier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the [definition](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=known+synonym), yes, it's okay:

> known
>
> /nəʊn/
>
> adjective
>
> **recognized, familiar, or within the scope of knowledge**.

Since the fact stated is based on humankind's current/existing knowledge regarding the identity of the first anatomist, there's no problem regarding the usage. (Hence if the scope of knowledge is updated, what is **known** shall change accordingly)

Comment: By the way, is it supposed to be "was" or "is" in this context?

Comment: "Is" should be used. (present tense is used when stating facts that are part of the current scope of knowledge, in general) Here's a link for reference: http://www.englishtenses.com/tenses/present_simple

Comment: For additional reference regarding the tense: this Google search is useful: https://www.google.co.uk/#q=%22archaeopteryx+is+the+first%22

Answer (score 3):

That is the correct way to use "known", yes. It directly means that the first anatomist we learned of, until we discover someone earlier, was Herophilos.

You can also say that Herophilos is the first anatomist that we know of, or just simply state that we do not know of any anatomists that practiced that craft before him.